# Como contar quantidade de linhas de um arquivo .csv

Tags: php, csv

Estou tentando contar a quantidade de linhas de um arquivo .csv mas dando erro

> Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in.

---

```
<?php
  ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);

  class Teste{
      public function contarLinhas($arquivo){
          $linhas = 0;
          if($f = fopen($arquivo, "r" )){
              while (!feof($f)) {
                  $linhas += 1;
              }
          }
          return $linhas;
      }
    }
?>
```

Comment: qual erro está ocorrendo?

Comment: Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in

Comment: já tentou set_time_limit(-1); ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema é que está em *loop* infinito; você só checa se está no final do arquivo mas não itera. Tenta assim:

```
while (!feof($f)) {
    $linhas += 1;
    $f->next();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Eu consegui fazendo um condigo diferente.

```
public function contarLinhasArquivo($arquivo){
    $linhas = 0;
    $linhas += count( file($arquivo) );
    return $linhas;
}
```